# for each, exchanging values / moving segment of content

Tags: excel, foreach, vba

So I wanted to move contents of two parallell but not connected ranges down, cell by cell, so I wrote an earlier and more detailed version of the following code and somehow i got it to work but now it doesn't.

```
Sub movedown()
Dim r As Range, r1 As Range, r2 As Range, r3 As Range, r4 As Range
Dim rc As Integer, str$

Set r = Intersect(Selection.EntireRow, Range("A:D"))
rc = r.Rows.Count
Set r1 = r.Columns(1)'for column A
Set r2 = r.Columns(4)'for column D
Set r3 = r1.Cells(1, 1).Offset(rc)'offsets to the cell beneath the selection
Set r4 = r2.Cells(1, 1).Offset(rc)'offsets to the cell beneath the selection

For Each c In r1
    str = r3.Value
    r3.Value = c.Value
    c.Value = str
Next c

For Each c In r2
    str = r4.Value
    r4.Value = c.Value
    c.Value = str
Next c

r.Offset(1).Select
End Sub
```

Example: (selected Range = A1:A4)
The idea was to exchange cell values between cells 1 and 5, then 2 and 5, then 3 and 5, then 4 and 5 and then move to the next range.

```
step  0 1 2 3 4
A1    a x x x x    
A2    b b a a a     
A3    c c c b b     
A4    d d d d c     
A5    x a b c d
```

Comment: In other words, are you looking to just shift the information down a cell? I can't quite tell what you're trying to do if not...

Comment: @BruceWayne  Yes, the last bit was part of the example, an attempt to make it look like the sheet in the steps of "For Each". So before running the sub A1=a, A2=b, A3=c, A4=d(the selected area) and A5=x. The result  should be A1=x, A2=a, A3=b, A4=c, A5=d. And since every loop starts from the top, my idea was to shift the values between A1 & A5 then A2 & A5 then A3 & A5 then A4 & A5 and after select A2:A5 . The result i get now is A1:A4= x and A5=a